# How much of Amazon Connect is scriptable, either through Terraform, Ansible or another approach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-connect

This question concerns AWS Connect, the cloud-based call center.  For those people who have been involved in the setup and configuration of AWS Connect, is there any portion of Amazon Connect that is configurable through a continuous integration flow other than any possible Lambda touchpoints. What I am looking for is scripting various functions such as loading exported flows, etc.

Looking at the AWS CLI, I see a number of AWS Connect calls but a majority is getting access to information (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/connect/index.html) but very few that are available to configure portions of AWS Connect.

Comment: It doesn't look like AWS exposes much in the way of things you can do via the API for Connect as you can see in the [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html). Terraform could, in theory, be used to manage the users but there's not a resource currently there, presumably because of the lack of other APIs around Connect.

Comment: Yes, I saw that also. I was hoping that someone who had done an AWS Connect implementation could shed light on what they did, if anything, around the CI/CD.

Answer (score 3):

There is basically nothing at this time. All contact flows must be imported/exported by hand. Other settings (e.g. routing profiles, prompts, etc.) must be re-created manually.

Someone has created a ["beta" Connect CloudFormation template](https://github.com/iann0036/amazon-connect-cfn) though that actually uses puppeteer behind the scenes to automate the import/export process. I imagine that Amazon will eventually support this, because devops is certainly one of the rough edges of the platform right now.

Comment: Thanks for the head's up.  I did take a look at the site you linked but unfortunately, my client will not approve such a "beta" approach.

Answer (score 2):

For new people checking this question. Amazon has [recently published](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amazon-connect-launches-contact-flow-management-apis/) the APIs you are looking for. [create-contact-flow](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/connect/create-contact-flow.html)

It uses a [JSON-based language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/flow-language-example.html) specific to Amazon Connect, below is an example:

```
{
"Version": "2019-10-30",
"StartAction": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
"Metadata": {
    "EntryPointPosition": {"X": 88,"Y": 100},
    "ActionMetadata": {
        "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012": {
            "Position": {"X": 270, "Y": 98}
        },
        "abcdef-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdefghijkl": {
            "Position": {"X": 545, "Y": 92}
        }

    }
},
"Actions": [
    {
        "Identifier": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
        "Type": "MessageParticipant",
        "Transitions": {
            "NextAction": "abcdef-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdefghijkl",
            "Errors": [],
            "Conditions": []
        },
        "Parameters": {
            "Prompt": {
                "Text": "Thanks for calling the sample flow!",
                "TextType": "text",
                "PromptId": null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Identifier": "abcdef-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdefghijkl",
        "Type": "DisconnectParticipant",
        "Transitions": {},
        "Parameters": {}
    }
]
}
```

Exporting from the GUI does not produce a JSON in this format. Obviously, a problem with this is keeping a state. I am keeping a close eye on Terraform/CloudFormation/CDK and will update this post if there is any support (that does not use puppeteer).

Comment: Just be aware that the contact flow  in the json based language is a json object within the json object returned from the DescribeContactFlow API call.  This means it's escaped.  Also to restore a contact flow you will need more than just the contact flow itself you will need to provide other AWS Connect metadata too.

Comment: True that the Contact Flow will require some work but i think the contact flows are the least issue. this could be resolved by writing a parser and producer script and just using the git ops approach you can be able to integrate it into a CI/CD. at the moment i just opened an issue for Terraform to add the resources if i got the time i may work on it. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16392

Answer (score 1):

I think it's doable now; with the newest APIs, you can do many things to script the entire process. There are some issues with the contact flows themself, but I think this will improve over the next few months.

In the meantime, there is some effort to add Amazon Connet to Terraform. here are the issues and the WIP PRs

- [Github Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16392)
- [Service PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/16644)
- [Resource PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/16709)